# how to call angular's Function synchronously to return the function result outside of angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, synchronized

how to call angular's Function synchronously  to return the function result outside of angular :
From Outside Angular : I am trying to call controller 's function in Angular to save data -using $http- and then from outside the angular scope I need to use the saving result for the next step. 
here is the code : 
from outside angular :

```
result= angular.element(divcurrency).scope().$apply('saveAll()');
if (result =="valid") 
{
....
}
```

and the controller function "saveAll" is :

```
this.saveAll= function ()
    {
        var task = $q.defer();

            $http.post(RESTUrl, $scope.dataToSave).then(function (response) {

                task.resolve(response.data);
                 return  response.data;
            }, function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                task.reject(response.data);
                return response.error;
            });
        })
        return task.promise;
    }
```

but unfortunately that function is executed asynchronously and cann't see the returned result, and I am not sure if I can use the promise from outside of angular .
I understand angular recommand using asynch process but at this situation I have to wait the result and be used outside of angular
 any help would be appreciated .

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to learn how to use promises.  (for example, you don't need `defer()`)

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of angular"?

Comment: @tavnab : outside of angular meant by outside of ng-app  scope : in otherway  I am using angular for  part of HTML  (specific Div) but the other parts  are  Old  code (mix HTML , VBScript and Javascript) and I don't want to interrept  them with the angular , the angular is applied only for this DIV.

Comment: @Slaks : I can remove defer() but the matter with me how can I call function synchronisly to save data (using HTTP) from outside angular and get the result to be used in other places ......

Comment: @Nahed: That is completely impossible.  http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: @SLaks: so can I return a promise  and use it outside of angular ? like promise= angular.element(divcurrency).scope().$apply('saveAll()').then (function (){//success} , function () {--error }) .... if not any other solution to get the result from outside angular? otherwise if that is really impossible so this is the negative side in angular and better to use jquery for this .....

Comment: @Nahed: Of course.  The term "outside of Angular" is meaningless; Javascript code is code no matter what you're writing it for.

Comment: @SLaks : i update last comment any example you can provided on how to use the promise ? outside of angular ng-app (scope) :like promise= angular.element(divcurrency).scope().$apply('saveAll()').then (function (){//success} , function () {--error })

Comment: @Nahed: Promises are normal objects that are not inherently tied to Angular in any way.  You can just call `.then()`.

Comment: @SLaks : This is very usefull and solved my issue  , I didn't know promise is a general , i ve just tried to use the same concept .then() and it is working fine , I don't know how to flag your comment as an answer .

Comment: Read http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-05/introducing-promises/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

Instead, you should return and use the promise directly.

The term "outside of Angular" is meaningless; you can use objects from anywhere you want to.